# Display date/time in Ubuntu lock screen (cinnamon-like)

Tags: unity, themes, cinnamon, lock-screen, screensaver

I was using Ubuntu 13.04 until a few days ago.
I had installed Nemo and I guess cinnamon got installed too (I was still using Unity nonetheless).

One of the good things about that was the **lock screen** which somehow changed to mimick cinnamon's (with the background as a darkened version of desktop background and date/time displayed), something like this:

[image]

I have no idea how this happened, but it looked great.

It does not seem to work on Ubuntu 13.10.
Anyone has any ideas to get a similar lock screen? I just need to display the date/time on one side with the backgroung as a darkened version of my desktop wallpaper.

Comment: If you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` is MDM in the list that appears?

Comment: nothing appears when I run the command. There is no output on the terminal